# AddOn: Bartender4 custom condition - change scale of bar on keypress

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Can you tell me if it's possible to use the Bartender4 custom conditions to change the scale of an actionbar triggered by keypress?

If i's possible to use the conditions I'd aprreciate any hint to documentation on how to write them.

Comment: So, basically you want to change the size based on keypress?

Comment: @ViniciusTerrabuio exactly!

Comment: Well, I know that bartender keeps the frames you configured all locked after youre done editing them, so it seems a little odd the concept of changing frame sizes while the interface is "hot" im not saying its not possible, but it is something to think about a little more..

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a condition to check for a certain key since Bartender uses the normal macro conditions, which do not have that.

There is another and pretty easy way to accomplish your wish... and even more if you like. You could easily make own UIs and switch to them in raids, instances or whatever you like. And you can still use conditions there.

1. You need two or more profiles in BT4.

   - one with your normal UI
   - one with the resized or rescaled bar(s)
   - (whatever else you need)
2. Make the same amount of macros in WoW:

   2.1. `/bt profiles choose profile1`  (the *name* of the first Bartender profile)
   2.2. `/bt profiles choose profile2`  (name of the 2nd profile)
   2.3. ...and so on

Now when you keybind your macros as you would usually do (drag and drop then on your action bar) you can use them to switch to another profile, which would then re-scale your action bar or whatever else you've changed.